# What are the adjacency bonuses for building districts next to each other - and to the city?

Tags: civilization-6

I saw in a Civ 6 video that you get bonuses for building districts next to each other - and the city proper is also counted as a district.

I can't find details written down anywhere or in Civilopedia.

What are these bonuses & when are they activated - I can find nothing online?

Comment: It's right there in the Civilopedia on the pages for each district.

Comment: I guess I was looking for one page with them all listed on - which is really handy (and is the accepted answer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> - **District Name** -    Adjacency bonus

- **Aerodrome** -  N/A
- **Aqueduct** -   N/A
- **Campus** - Bonus Science when placed next to: Mountains, Rainforest
  (per 2 tiles), Other Districts (per 2 districts)
- **City Centre** -    None (bestows adjacency bonuses to some other districts)
- **Commercial Hub** - Bonus Gold when placed next to: Rivers, Harbour,
  Other Districts (per 2 districts)
- **Encampment** - N/A
- **Entertainment Complex** -  N/A
- **Harbour** -    Bonus Gold when placed next to: Coastal Resources, Other
  Districts (per 2 districts)
- **Holy Site** -  Bonus Faith when placed next to: Natural Wonders,
  Mountains, Woods (per 2 tiles), Other Districts (per 2 districts)
- **Industrial Zone** -    Bonus Production when placed next to: Mines,
  Quarry, Other Districts (per 2 districts)
- **Neighbourhood** -  N/A
- **Space Port** - N/A
- **Theatre Square** - Bonus Culture when placed next to: Wonders, Other
  Districts (per 2 districts)

-[source](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2016-10-21-civilization-6-districts-best-tile-placement-adjacency-bonuses-4879)

Comment: Note that some civs have replacements for some of the above, and usually they have improved bonuses. E.g. the Greek replacement for the Theatre Square yields +1 culture per district (double the usual bonus).